# How do I count the amount of iterations in a while loop?

Tags: python, while-loop

How do I print how many times a while loop has run?

Example:

```
from random import*

c=0

while c<3 :

    a=randint(1,6)

    b=randint(1,6)

    if a==b:
       print(a,b)
       c=c+1
```

Comment: Add a `counter` variable which is (unconditionally) increased each iteration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add another counter.

```
from random import *
c = 0
loop_counter = 0
while c < 3:
  a = randint(1,6)
  b = randint(1,6)
  if a==b:
     print(a,b)
     c += 1
  loop_counter += 1

print(f"The loop run {loop_counter} times.")
```

Answer (score 0):

By adding a "counter variable", something that increases for each loop.

As an example:

```
from random import*

c=0
counter = 0 #define

while c<3 :
    counter += 1 #add one 
    print (counter) #print
    a=randint(1,6)

    b=randint(1,6)

    if a==b:
       print(a,b)
       c=c+1
```

You can also just print "counter" after the while loop has ended to get a final tally.

Answer (score 0):

```
from random import *

c=0
Counter=0
while c<3 :

    a=randint(1,6)

    b=randint(1,6)

    if a==b:
       print(a,b)
       c=c+1
    Counter+=1

print (Counter)
```

Comment: I strongly advice against using variable names with first letter capitalized. It is wrong code style (it then looks as a class Counter)

Comment: Generally code-only answers are discouraged. Please [edit] to include a description of the change you made, and why you made it. Also please point it out with comments in the code. And please take some time to read about [how to write good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: if you are happy with the answer , I will be grateful if you vote .